# what's the benefits of using `resolve` in angular route modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Both `ngRoute` and `UI Router` provide `resolve` method on url definitions which should resolve before the route is loaded. I've seen a lot of pages explaining how to use it but almost none define benefits for using it. At the moment, I clearly see one good fit usage of it, which is to prevent not authorized access to views/data. This usage is more related to security.

In the examples I've seen it's mostly used to get and inject initial data into controller, but I can also easily do that using service within a controller. So why use `resolve`? Moreover, by using `resolve` I should handle `rejected` promise when data is not available for some reason. The controller which should receive that data won't even be initialized and so I should handle `routeChangeFailed` event on `$rootScope` to decide how to proceed. Besides, I also somehow should pass information on what route failed and why.

So again, two questions:
1) What's the benefits of using `resolve` method for data retrieval?
2) What are the common approaches to handling rejections/failed data retrieval situations?

PS. Any good read about the topic is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What's the benefits of using resolve method for data retrieval?

You dont want your views to render before you get the required data to be displayed , this is what the purpose of using  `resolve` in routes.

It is useless to display half of the view with out having `{{necessary. requirements}}`  (these brackets are intentional)

Authorized data ,data that is major part of the view or data that if not loaded before the view is rendered will take out the value from the view(template) is better to be loaded before the `view` is actually rendered

For example you have user profile that mostly has user data, it is useless to render the view with dozens of ng-if without having actual data isn't?

> What are the common approaches to handling rejections/failed data
>   retrieval situations

`redirecting` to other `routes` or the routes is preferred but it depeds on the logic.

you can catch the rejection in $routechangerror or again it depend on your logic

**Simple example for handling rejection:**

route resolve

```
.when('/seedata', 
     { 
      templateUrl: '/partials/seedata.html',
      controller: 'abcCtrl',
       resolve: {
        data : function(dataService){
           if(dataService.hasData()) {
              return true;
           } 
           else {
               return $q.reject('no data');
            }
        }
      }
    });
```

handling resolve at run phase

```
angular.module('test').run(function($rootScope, $location) {
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeError', function(evt, current, previous, rejection) {
    if(rejection === 'no data') {
      $location.path('#/wait');
    }
  })

 })
```

Comment: Thanks, but I could easily achieve the same using `ng-if` to prevent views from being rendered until I get my initial data from the service inside a controller.

Comment: _redirecting to other routes_ - where? Inside the factory function used for resolution?

Comment: @Maximus see tghe updated answer the last part/para of first question

Comment: @Maximus i have also updated the rejecion portion of the answer

Comment: Thanks, but I can't understand this part: _that if not loaded will take out the value form the view_ in this sentence _Authorized data or data that is major part of the view is beneficial to be loaded before the view is actually rendered_. Can you please rephrase it?

Comment: @Maximus see if it is understandable now?

Comment: Yeah, it's clear now, thanks! Do you any good read about the other benefits of `resolve`?

Comment: i cant recall the exact links , i will paste it as i find in my bin.